# How to execute JUnit TestSuite with some delay between each TestCase?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have two JUnit4 Test classes say MyTest1, MyTest2 each having a couple of test methods.
Actually these are Selenium JUnit TestCases.

In MyTest1.someMethodInsertingDate() i will insert some data into DB and it will take some time to process.

In MyTest2.validateProcessedData() I need to verify that the processed data inserted in the first test method is valid or not.

I know coupling between test methods/cases is not a good practice. But I am writing SeleniumTests to automate User Actions on UI, so I have to do this.

I am executing these two TestCases using MyTestSuite with @RunWith & @SuiteClasses.

Now How can I tell JUnit to execute MyTest2 TestCase with some delay,say 1 minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're not getting an answer (at least not one you want) to this question because it is generally considered bad practice to rely upon these mechanics in a test suite.  Your tests will become very difficult to maintain if you have these types of reliance upon each other, and can (most likely will) cause you difficulty in debugging them later.

You could possibly abstract this first test out, and this second test could perhaps extend it.  This second test will then use the common functionality in its setup (perhaps with different data).  This should allow you to run the tests concurrently since each will then be an atomic entity.

Comment: You are right. Coupling b/w test cases is a bad practice. So finally i moved the dependent test methods into private methods, calling them from test case putting sleep() in between them.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the simple "@Before" annotation.
It should delay the execution thread each time it starts the test.

Example:

```
@Before
public void initialise() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As we hopefully all agree that this is bad practice in general there are exceptions.
To state the obvious, we're not talking about unit tests but integration tests (JUnit might not be the right tool for the job but I haven't found anything better)

I am doing Selenium tests as well. I do integration testing against 3rd party test server which behavior is random if I run tests without sleep().

This is one of the possible solutions, please note that this was only tested by running once:

```
public class SleepySuite extends Suite {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SleepySuite.class);
    private final Integer defaultSleepSec = 0;
    private final Integer sleepSec;

    public SleepySuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, builder);
        sleepSec = initSleep(klass);
    }

    private Integer initSleep(Class<?> klass) {
        SleepSec ts = klass.getAnnotation(SleepSec.class);
        Integer sleep = defaultSleepSec;
        if (ts != null) {
            sleep = ts.value();
            log.debug("Configured with sleep time: {}s", sleep);
        }
        return sleep;
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Inherited
    public @interface SleepSec {
        public int value();
    }

    /**
     * @see org.junit.runners.Suite#runChild(org.junit.runner.Runner, org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier)
     */
    @Override
    protected void runChild(Runner runner, RunNotifier notifier) {
        super.runChild(runner, notifier);
        //Simply wrapped Thread.sleep(long)
        TestUtils.sleep(sleepSec);
    }
}
```

Your suite exmaple:

```
@RunWith(SleepySuite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
   Some.class,
   SomeOther.class
})
@SleepySuite.TimeoutSec(30)
public class YourSuite{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sharing for posterity,

The usage of `Thread#sleep` in the JUnit test always be discouraged by static code analysis tool like `sonarqube`. Instead of using the aforementioned approach prefer some libraries like `Awaitility`. Though it is not an ideal solution, this is a much better approach than the usage of `Thread#sleep`.

Required code changes:

```
    testImplementation('org.awaitility:awaitility:4.0.3')
```

Put the below snippet in the place where you require to place some delay. In the following example, I have set the delay duration time as one second. Conceptually, this will do the same task as `Thread.sleep(1000)`

```
Awaitility.await().pollDelay(Durations.ONE_SECOND).until(() -> true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can induce some wait in Java in the first test case after your database code like this:

long end3 = System.currentTimeMillis() + 6000;

```
        while(System.currentTimeMillis()<end3)
        {
            // Do nothing here Just time pass.  
        }
```

This will ensure that Java code waits for 6000 ms after the DB code and that should be enough to add the data. You can adjust time according to the size of your data.

Answer (score -2):

You can sleep the script by adding something at the end of each test method.
In PHP:

```
sleep(60);
```